# Match the SSN patterns if both delimiter are same

Tags: java, regex

need to match the ssn numbers only if both delimiters should match. But below code matches all.

```
((?:\d[-.\s]*?){9})
```

Input:

```
list of ssn are 222-33-4444, 333.77-8888 and 111 77.9998 and 111 22 3333 and 11-222222-9
```

Expected output:

```
222-33-4444
111 22 3333
11-222222-9
```

Comment: (?<!\d)\d{3}([^\d])\d{2}\1\d{4}(?!\d)

Comment: @ChrisMaurer the format isn't fixed as 3-2-4 (see the last expected output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the first delimiter and then use a back-reference to assert that the second delimiter is the same character. Since the format can be variable in terms of delimiter placement, you also need to assert that there are 9 digits and 2 delimiters:

```regex
\b(?=[\d. -]{11}\b)\d{1,}([. -])\d{1,}\1\d{1,}\b
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/v2CzeN/2)

If the SSN may be adjacent to word characters, `\b` will not work (as there is no word boundary between a digit and a word character) and you will need to use negative lookarounds to assert the SSN is not preceded or followed by other digits:

```regex
(?<!\d)(?=[\d. -]{11}(?!\d))\d{1,}([. -])\d{1,}\1\d{1,}(?!\d)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EInQez/2)

If the SSN may have no delimiters, you can just add `\d{9}` (9 digits) as an alternation to the regex:

```regex
(?<!\d)(?:(?=[\d. -]{11}(?!\d))\d{1,}([. -])\d{1,}\1\d{1,}|\d{9})(?!\d)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/U3yWhb/1)

Comment: but the numbers won't be in same format it can be 22-33335-99. The patern is not fixed XXX-XX-XXXX

Comment: @Sadu you should update your question to reflect **all** possible forms of input data...

Comment: @Sadu see my edit

Comment: @Sadu if you follow my demo link, the right hand side of the page has an explanation of what the regex is doing. It's a great site for testing ideas on.

Comment: one more help, why it's not identify if there is a alphabet prefix or sufix like  a222-33-4444 or 222-33-4444b

Comment: @Sadu see my edit, there's a regex which will match those OK

Comment: how to handel tis ssn123456789. need to capture the 9 digtis in same regex

Comment: @Sadu so there can be no delimiters? What about 1 delimiter?

Comment: in this case no delimiter im getting SSN as char followed by 9 digits like ssn123456789 or ssn:123456789 or ssn#123456789.  Sorry i'm asking too much. i am new here. please assist

Comment: if its complicated, please help with seperate regex for the continous case alone ssn123456789 or ssn:123456789 or ssn#123456789

Comment: @Sadu see my edit

Comment: @Sadu just ask another question - it will get seen by a lot more people (including me) and you might get some even better answers

Comment: this scenerio act differently. If i give 083 09 0 88   it capture 083 09 alone rather than full number? or 083 09 0 009.00 .. please assist

Comment: @Sadu it's not possible to avoid that match in any realistic way with regex. You should unaccept this answer and look for a different approach

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for costly lookahead or lookbehind:

```
\d+(\D)\d+\1\d+
```

Since your question is tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java):

```
ssn.length() == 11 && ssn.matches("\\d+(\\D)\\d+\\1\\d+")
```

Comment: nice !!, but is it possible to restrict 9 digits + 2 delimiters in regex itself. First i identify all 9 digit numbers based on regex patten and pass the numbers to java while loop

Comment: @Sadu Is there a reason you need to do all of the validation with a single regular expression?

Comment: i am scaning a free form text fields, the data is unstructured so trying to identify in SSN numbers having nine digits in first place. I don't know how the 9 digit numbers will be placed. Example data like : my ssn is 123-45-6789 and 2nd one withour space  SSN123456789 and third ssn is 12 345678 9.

Comment: I ask again:  is there a reason you need to do all of the validation with a single regular expression?  Why not use a simple, *readable* regular expression and check the length separately?  The code will be considerably more readable and easier for you (and others) to maintain.

Comment: the input string is big it has more than one SSN numbers, first i capture all the 9 digits in string and process one by one in while loop. I don't know the actual SSN in first place. need to find in input string and then process on it